# how can I use the same virbr0 in both qemu:///system and qemu:///session?

Tags: libvirt

The libvirt has a default network bridge: virbr0
If I use `virsh net-list --all` i can see a default bridge: virbr0
If I use `virsh -c qemu:///session net-list --all` There is nothing
Then I just did

```
virsh net-dumpxml default > default.xml
virsh -c qemu:///session net-define --file default.xml
```

however, the default is inactive in session

```
$ virsh -c qemu:///system net-list --all
 Name      State    Autostart   Persistent
--------------------------------------------
 default   active   yes         yes
$ virsh -c qemu:///session net-list --all
 Name      State      Autostart   Persistent
----------------------------------------------
 default   inactive   no          yes
```

if I try to start the default network, it said:

```
$ virsh -c qemu:///session net-start default
error: Failed to start network default
error: internal error: Network is already in use by interface virbr0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

actually there is no need to add the network into session. Directly use the virbr0 is fine.

Comment: some explanation goes a long way